# The results of Toffoli gate are quite different from those of simulation

Tags: quantum-gate

[image]

[image]

The simulation result is 111, but the actual result is 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by noise in quantum circuit. When you use a simulator, usually there is no noise (unless it is simulated), so you have ideal quantum computer. However, in reality, a quantum processor is influenced by thermal and electromagnetic noise. Current challenge for quantum computer designers it to shield the noise from qubits.

Qubits also suffer from decoherence. This means that qubits randomly change state from 0 to 1 (spontaneous excitation) or from 1 to 0 (spontaneous relaxation). Additionally the qubits phase can also change. Of course, decoherence is connected with noise, however, quantum nature of qubits also causes the decoherence. This is also chalange for the designers - to avoid decoherence as much as possible and enlong the time the qubits work as expected.

Try to increase number of shot for algorithm run on actual quantum computer. It can help to get "better" results. Also, try to run the algorithm on different backends.

---

**EDIT** (*Comments added by JSdJ*):

Decoherence is not really spontaneous excitation or relaxation, it has more to do with the degrading of the relative phase of the qubit; to some extent it's the process that destroys the thing in the qubit what makes it 'quantum'. Spontaneous relaxation is also known as amplitude damping, and is a much larger problem than spontaneous excitation.

Moreover, the noise apparent in these results is more a result of the imperfect gates rather than the degradation of the qubits themselves (which would also be apparent if they were idle). Noise stemming from imperfect gates is tricky and doesn't normally allow such a 'clean' noise model as the deph. or amp. channel. It will also greatly depend on the actual system that is being used. As a last note, if you increase the number of shots in the actual computation, this will not limit the intrinsic noise in the quantum system. It will diminish the effect of statistical noise, however

Comment: (1/2) Decoherence is not really spontaneous excitation or relaxation, it has more to do with the degrading of the relative phase of the qubit; to some extent it's the process that destroys the thing in the qubit what makes it 'quantum'. Spontaneous relaxation is also known as amplitude damping, and is a much larger problem than spontaneous excitation.

Comment: (2/2) Moreover, the noise apparent in these results is more a result of the imperfect gates rather than the degradation of the qubits themselves (which would also be apparent if they were idle). Noise stemming from imperfect gates is tricky and doesn't normally allow such a 'clean' noise model as the deph. or amp. channel. It will also greatly depend on the actual system that is being used.

As a last note, if you increase the number of shots in the actual computation, this will not limit the intrinsic noise in the quantum system. It will diminish the effect of statistical noise, however.

Comment: @JSdJ: Thanks for expanding my answer, plese feel free to post your comments as additional answer, I would vote +1

Comment: I think you already have a good answer that catches the core concepts, feel free to add my comments though!